# Getting SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound in E:\wamp64\www\social\classes\db.php on line 12 error

Tags: mysql, pdo

I'm making a social network's login page but when I login a get the error above. My db.php is (i use pdo):

```
<?php
class DB {

    private static function connect() {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=social;charset=utf8', 'danny', 'password');
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $pdo;
    }

    public static function query($query, $params = array()) {
        $statement = self::connect()->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute($params);

        if (explode(' ', $query)[0] == 'SELECT') {
            $data = $statement->fetchAll();
            return $data;
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Called from

```
$user_id = DB::query('SELECT id 
                      FROM users 
                      WHERE email=:email')[0]['id']; 

DB::query('INSERT INTO login_tokens 
            VALUES(\'\', :token, :user_id)',        
        array(':token'=>sha1($token), ':user_id'=>$user_id));
```

Comment: That error is related to the query and its parameters that you pass to this function. Show the call to `DB::query()` and the parameters you pass that is where the error is

Comment: $user_id = DB::query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE email=:email')[0]['id'];
DB::query('INSERT INTO login_tokens VALUES(\'\', :token, :user_id)', array(':token'=>sha1($token), ':user_id'=>$user_id));

Comment: The way yo have coded this, every time you want to execute a query you will make a connection to the database. Thats a major waste of time. Save the connection (`$pdo`) as a class property and use it in the other methods

Comment: Well now you can read the calls the erro should be obvious right

Answer (score -1):

Your class has many issues. to fix them:

```
class DB {

    protected static $pdo;

    public static function connect() {
        static::$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=social;charset=utf8', 'danny', 'Dani2034');
        static::$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }

    public static function query($query, $params = array()) {
        $statement = self::$pdo->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute($params);
        return $statement;
    }
}

DB::connect(); // called only once

$user_id = DB::query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE email=?', array($email))->fetchColumn(); 
DB::query('INSERT INTO login_tokens VALUES(null, ?, ?)', array(sha1($token), $user_id));
```

Comment: Error: Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array in E:\wamp64\www\social\login.php on line 28

Comment: DO IT EXACTLY AS SHOWN ABOVE. Returning an array is silly.

Comment: I did exactly like that.

Comment: You didn't. you tried to use your silly [0]['id'] stuff

Comment: Then I tried your code, but it didn't worked, but i resolved that, thanks anyway.

Comment: My code works. Some your other code may be caused this error. You should change it accordingly. Make this function return the exact result you need instead of returning a blunt array all the time.